# rails: redirect_to with object params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to redirect_to with object parameters. I've tried doing it different ways but none of them worked.

```
redirect_to user_path(params[:current_user.id])

redirect_to user_path(params[:current_user(params[:id])])
```

How am I supposed to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 redirect_to user_path(current_user)
 #=> redirects to users/:id where :id is current_user.id
```

Answer (score 1):

How about just:

```
redirect_to user_path(current_user.id)
```